# is it possible to cache a button?

Tags: javascript, createjs

I am working on converting the flash game to createjs. I am using adobe animate cc 2017  Facing performance issues. Memory is growing higher. WhenI GOOGLE it I want to add cache. I started adding in the converted flash file which does not have animations. When I added and test it I lost the button effects. is there any way that I can cache a button

Comment: Can you explain your problem easily ? I cannot understand what is the point.

Comment: If the memory is an issue, what generally helps for me outside of caching, is putting more calculations into the application instead of storing everything in variables. So this means, if you do a calculation and store it in a variable, it gets saved into the RAM. By not storing it into a variable, it'll be more CPU intensive, but save you the RAM... pretty much. But if it's ALSO CPU intensive, this advice is useless.

Answer (score 1):

A button created in Animate (I assume using the ButtonHelper?) is essentially a MovieClip with different states that activate when you interact with it. If you cache a MovieClip, it will store the current state into a single cache-canvas, which is why it will no longer update.

If your Button has vector or complex states, you *could* cache those frames instead, and leave the Button/MovieClip un-cached. It would help to see what the contents contain. Feel free to post some code, and I can update my answer with some suggestions.

**About EaselJS Caching**

Caching is valuable when you have vector, text, or grouped content that don't change a lot. It is even better if you can group those caches into a shared SpriteSheet, which helps the GPU manage less textures. Note that simply "caching things" will not necessarily get you back any performance depending on what you are doing.